# Loop is not working as expected on the pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a function that takes in two parameters, one is a pyspark data frame and the other is a list of variable names from a config file. I am trying to create a loop on the list and check if those variables are null or not in the dataframe. Then append the column with the prefix "_NullCheck". Right now what is happening is that only the last variable in my list shows in the output dataframe. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code so far.

```
def nullCheck(df, configfile2):
    nullList = getNullList(configfile2)

    for nullCol in nullList:
        subset_df = df.withColumn(f"{nullCol}_NullCheck",
                        when(df[f"{nullCol}"].isNull(), "Y" )
                        .otherwise("N"))

    return subset_df
```

Comment: Well you are overwriting subset_df for every iteration of your loop, so it stands to reason only the last iteration would get returned.

Comment: @Chris I see what you mean. How would I append to the dataframe instead of just iterating on the same dataset?

Comment: why not just change `subset_df` to `df` and return `df`

Comment: Because I am running Data Quality checks and will be storing the output in an external file. This is just one of the functions that will run through the data frame. I do not want to append it to the original data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The df you are modifying is local so the scope of the function, so you can modify it in place and select only the new columns.  The original df will remain unchanged.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, None),
                            (1, None, 3),
                            (None, 2, 3)], ['col1','col2','col3'])

nullList = ['col1','col2']

def nullCheck(df):
  return df.select([when(col(c).isNull(), 'Y').otherwise('N').alias(f'{c}_Null_Check') for c in nullList])

nulls = nullCheck(df)
nulls.show()
```

Output

```
+---------------+---------------+
|col1_Null_Check|col2_Null_Check|
+---------------+---------------+
|              N|              N|
|              N|              Y|
|              Y|              N|
+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: This worked for me but the only thing I would change is the col(c). It should actually be df[f"{c}"].isNull()

Answer (score 0):

```
def nullCheck(df, configfile2):
nullList = getNullList(configfile2)
subset_df = []
for nullCol in nullList:
    subset_df.append(df.withColumn(f"{nullCol}_NullCheck",
                    when(df[f"{nullCol}"].isNull(), "Y" )
                    .otherwise("N")))

return subset_df
```

Comment: This approach did not work unfortunately. I get the 'list' object has no attribute 'show' error.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `withColumn()` constructs are generally bad if there are a lot of columns (like a lot!). Try using list comprehension within `select()`.

```
def nullCheck(df, configfile2):
    nullList = getNullList(configfile2)

    subset_df = df. \
        select('*', 
               *[func.when(func.col(nullCol).isNull(), func.lit('Y')).
                 otherwise(func.lit('N')).alias(nullCol+'_NullCheck') 
                 for nullCol in nullList]
               )

    return subset_df
```